# How to add a xml node set to existing file using c#

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

Below is my XML,

```
<MultiCentreDeals>
    <DealItem>
      <ID>24</ID>
      <Days>
         <Day>
          <DayID>24-1</DayID>
          <DayTitle>Day 13</DayTitle>
      </Day>
      <Day>
          <DayID>24-2</DayID>
          <DayTitle>Day 2</DayTitle>
      </Day>
     </Days>
   </DealItem>
   <DealItem>
      <ID>25</ID>
      <Days>
         <Day>
          <DayID>25-1</DayID>
          <DayTitle>Day 3</DayTitle>
      </Day>
      <Day>
          <DayID>25-2</DayID>
          <DayTitle>Day 4</DayTitle>
      </Day>
     </Days>
   </DealItem>
</MultiCentreDeals>
```

First I want to select the data according to the ID(25) and add a   set to that. I tried many ways and didn't work anything can anyone please tell me how to do? Below way I tried to select particular Data belong to ID(25) but am not sure it is correct or not.

```
  XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("/Xml/MultiCentreDealDetails.xml"));
  Dictionary<string, XElement> CompleteDealSet = doc.Descendants("DealItem").GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("ID"), y => y).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
  XElement Selected_Deal = CompleteDealSet[mc_ID];

  Dictionary<string, XElement> ItinerarySet = Selected_Deal.Descendants("Day").GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("DayID"), y => y).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: your xml file should end with </MultiCentreDeals> (else it will not be loaded) then you can try to append child to a selected node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me,

```
   XElement saveData = Selected_Deal.Element("Days");
   saveData.Add(new XElement("Day",
   new XElement("DayID", newDayID),
   new XElement("DayTitle", multicentreDay)));
   doc.Save(Server.MapPath("/Xml/MultiCentreDealDetails.xml"));
```